# Error:(14, 45) error: unclosed character literal

Tags: android

I have an error in `NEWS_API_KEY` when I edited it return back in this class

```java
/* Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY */

package com.news.droiddebo.mytimes;
    
public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
    public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.news.droiddebo.mytimes";
    public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
    public static final String FLAVOR = "";
    public static final int VERSION_CODE = 5;
    public static final String VERSION_NAME = "2.0";
    // Fields from build type: debug
    public static final String NEWS_API_KEY = '1da651fa26f34134bb880c82ff7f0541';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *double quote* (`"`) instead of a single quote while initializing a `String` variable:

```java
public static final String NEWS_API_KEY = "1da651fa26f34134bb880c82ff7f0541";
```

Comment: i used the double  but when i sync the project the quote return back like this  
`"1da651fa26f34134bb880c82ff7f0541"`

Comment: files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited "this the message pop up

Comment: Error:(14, 45) error: unclosed character literal
Error:(14, 78) error: unclosed character literal
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: I think you have make same mistake in another variable. So please verify whole code once.

Comment: yes the problem it was iam using single quote in gradle.properties i fixed thanks